# docker issue while starting container "error while mounting source path"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, server, io, mounted-volumes

I microservice configured in docker with mysql/ rabbitMQ and cache container separately.. usually I am facing below issue when I am trying to run the docker. I am using window. this issue is not consistent. it comes occasionally, but when it comes then even after trying multiple time issue still persist. even after docker restart it still the same.. any suggestion

Error invoking remote method 'docker-start-container': Error: (HTTP code 500) server error - error while creating mount source path '/run/desktop/mnt/host/d/project/project1': mkdir /run/desktop/mnt/host/d/project/project1: input/output error